# Can dbms_errlog be used for SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can the `dbms_errlog` function be used for SELECT queries?

I earlier encountered an error where Oracle is throwing an `ORA-0722`, i was trying to identify which column and possibly, row of a PL/SQL statement that was throwing that error. However i found out that dbms_errlog is native to only Oracle 10g and above.

In the case also, what alternatives do i have if i am using Oracle 9i?

Comment: That's a very general question, can you be more specific? show the offending code / table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS_ERRLOG ist not a function, it is a PL/SQL package. It contains one procedure that creates an error table. To log errors to this error, you need to specify the "log errors" clause to your DML statements. From this description it should be obvious that this is tightly integrated with the transaction layer.

One way to reproduce similar behavior in earlier releases is to

- Create your own error table
- Create a PL/SQL procedure that inserts into that error table. To
  make sure that the log is written in case of errors this procedure has to use
  autonomous transactions.
- The calls to log errors have to be explicitly added to the
  corresponding exception handlers.